Failed to load system plugin [gz_ros2_control-system] : couldn't find shared library
Using ROS2 Humble on Ubuntu Jammy 22.04.4 LTS
Gazebo: Ignition Fortress
I have upgraded to Ignition Gazebo from classic, trying to get ROS2 simulation running again and I believe I have some path or missing config/ setup issue:
I have built gz_ros2_controls from source, and all of those demos work perfectly. This was built (as directed) into ~/ros2_ws
I can also run all of the ign_ros2_control demos (with direct ros2 launch commands) and they also work perfectly.
Now I'm trying to launch Ignition Gazebo from my ~/dev_ws.
I've made a new launch file which is almost a copy of the gz_ros2_control_demos sample file
My launch_sim_gz.launch.py file is below:
# Attempt at replacing launch_sim.launch.py with a newer one for new Gazebo
# Originally sourced from:
# https://github.com/ros-controls/gz_ros2_control/blob/master/gz_ros2_control_demos/launch/diff_drive_example.launch.py
import os

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory

# See the ros2/launch Source code
# e.g. launch/launch/actions/include_launch_description.py
# Docs: https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Intermediate/Launch/Launch-Main.html
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument, ExecuteProcess, IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.actions import RegisterEventHandler
from launch.event_handlers import OnProcessExit
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.substitutions import Command, FindExecutable, LaunchConfiguration, PathJoinSubstitution

from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch_ros.substitutions import FindPackageShare, FindPackagePrefix

def generate_launch_description():
    # Include the robot_state_publisher launch file, provided by our own package. Force sim time to be enabled
    package_name='my_bot'

    # Set the path to this package.
    pkg_share = FindPackagePrefix(package=package_name).find(package_name)
    pkg_path = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory(package_name))
    print("pkg_path: ", pkg_path)
    print("pkg_share: ", pkg_share)

    world_file_name = 'my_world.world'
    world_path = os.path.join(pkg_path,"worlds",world_file_name)
    print("Expecting world at: ",world_path)
    if os.path.isfile(world_path):
        print("Found world file!")
    else:
        print("ERROR did not find world file")

    # Launch Arguments
    use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time', default=True)

    # Get URDF via xacro
    robot_description_content = Command(
        [
            PathJoinSubstitution([FindExecutable(name='xacro')]),
            ' ',
            PathJoinSubstitution(
                [FindPackageShare(package_name),
                 'description', 'robot.urdf.xacro']
            ),
        ]
    )
    robot_description = {'robot_description': robot_description_content}

    node_robot_state_publisher = Node(
        package='robot_state_publisher',
        executable='robot_state_publisher',
        output='screen',
        parameters=[robot_description]
    )

    gz_spawn_entity = Node(
        package='ros_gz_sim',
        executable='create',
        output='screen',
        arguments=['-topic', 'robot_description', '-name',
                   package_name, '-allow_renaming', 'true'],
    )

    load_joint_state_broadcaster = ExecuteProcess(
        cmd=['ros2', 'control', 'load_controller', '--set-state', 'active',
             'joint_state_broadcaster'],
        output='screen'
    )

    load_diff_drive_controller = ExecuteProcess(
        cmd=['ros2', 'control', 'load_controller', '--set-state', 'active',
             'diff_drive_base_controller'],
        output='screen'
    )

    return LaunchDescription([
        # Launch gazebo environment
        IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
                [PathJoinSubstitution([FindPackageShare('ros_gz_sim'),
                                       'launch',
                                       'gz_sim.launch.py'])]),
            launch_arguments=[('gz_args', [' -r -v 4 empty.sdf'])]),
        RegisterEventHandler(
            event_handler=OnProcessExit(
                target_action=gz_spawn_entity,
                on_exit=[load_joint_state_broadcaster],
            )
        ),
        RegisterEventHandler(
            event_handler=OnProcessExit(
                target_action=load_joint_state_broadcaster,
                on_exit=[load_diff_drive_controller],
            )
        ),
        node_robot_state_publisher,
        gz_spawn_entity,
        # Launch Arguments
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'use_sim_time',
            default_value=use_sim_time,
            description='If true, use simulated clock'),
    ])


It loads a robot.urdf.xacro file which includes ros2_control.xacro and a few other files.
I've used xacro to stitch them all together (xacro ./src/my_bot/description/robot.urdf.xacro > stitched_robot.urdf) and this is the output file:
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!-- =================================================================================== -->
<!-- |    This document was autogenerated by xacro from ./src/my_bot/description/robot.urdf.xacro | -->
<!-- |    EDITING THIS FILE BY HAND IS NOT RECOMMENDED                                 | -->
<!-- =================================================================================== -->
<robot name="robot">
  <!-- Specify some standard inertial calculations https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia -->
  <!-- These make use of xacro's mathematical functionality -->
  <material name="white">
    <color rgba="1 1 1 1"/>
  </material>
  <material name="orange">
    <color rgba="1 0.3 0.1 1"/>
  </material>
  <material name="blue">
    <color rgba="0.2 0.2 1 1"/>
  </material>
  <material name="black">
    <color rgba="0 0 0 1"/>
  </material>
  <material name="red">
    <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
  </material>
  <!-- BASE LINK -->
  <link name="base_link">

    </link>
  <!-- BASE_FOOTPRINT LINK -->
  <joint name="base_footprint_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="base_footprint"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="base_footprint">
    </link>
  <!-- CHASSIS LINK -->
  <joint name="chassis_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="chassis"/>
    <origin xyz="-0.1 0 0"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="chassis">
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0.15 0 0.075"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.3 0.3 0.15"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="white"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0.15 0 0.075"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.3 0.3 0.15"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.25 0 0.075"/>
      <mass value="0.5"/>
      <inertia ixx="0.004687499999999999" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.004687499999999999" iyz="0.0" izz="0.0075"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>
  <gazebo reference="chassis">
    <material>Gazebo/White</material>
  </gazebo>
  <!-- LEFT WHEEL LINK -->
  <joint name="left_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="left_wheel"/>
    <origin rpy="-1.5707963267948966 0 0" xyz="0 0.175 0"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="left_wheel">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.04" radius="0.045"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="blue"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <sphere radius="0.045"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="0.1"/>
      <inertia ixx="6.395833333333333e-05" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="6.395833333333333e-05" iyz="0.0" izz="0.00010125"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>
  <gazebo reference="left_wheel">
    <material>Gazebo/Blue</material>
  </gazebo>
  <!-- RIGHT WHEEL LINK -->
  <joint name="right_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="right_wheel"/>
    <origin rpy="1.5707963267948966 0 0" xyz="0 -0.175 0"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 -1"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="right_wheel">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.04" radius="0.045"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="blue"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <sphere radius="0.045"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="0.1"/>
      <inertia ixx="6.395833333333333e-05" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="6.395833333333333e-05" iyz="0.0" izz="0.00010125"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>
  <gazebo reference="right_wheel">
    <material>Gazebo/Blue</material>
  </gazebo>
  <!-- Caster Wheel link -->
  <joint name="caster_wheel_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="chassis"/>
    <child link="caster_wheel"/>
    <origin xyz="0.24 0 0"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="caster_wheel">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <sphere radius="0.013"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="black"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <geometry>
        <sphere radius="0.013"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <inertial>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <mass value="0.1"/>
      <inertia ixx="6.7600000000000005e-06" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="6.7600000000000005e-06" iyz="0.0" izz="6.7600000000000005e-06"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>
  <gazebo reference="caster_wheel">
    <material>Gazebo/Black</material>
    <mu1 value="0.001"/>
    <mu2 value="0.001"/>
  </gazebo>
  <!-- <ros2_control name="RealRobot" type="system">
        <hardware>
            <plugin>diffdrive_arduino/DiffDriveArduino</plugin>
            <param name="left_wheel_name">left_wheel_joint</param>
            <param name="right_wheel_name">right_wheel_joint</param>
            <param name="loop_rate">30</param>
            <param name="device">/dev/ttyUSB0</param>
            <param name="baud_rate">57600</param>
            <param name="timeout">1000</param>
            <param name="enc_counts_per_rev">3436</param>            
        </hardware>
        <joint name="left_wheel_joint">
            <command_interface name="velocity">
                <param name="min">-10</param>
                <param name="max">10</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="velocity" />
            <state_interface name="position" />
        </joint>
        <joint name="right_wheel_joint">
            <command_interface name="velocity">
                <param name="min">-10</param>
                <param name="max">10</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="velocity" />
            <state_interface name="position" />
        </joint>
    </ros2_control> -->
  <ros2_control name="GazeboSimSystem" type="system">
    <hardware>
      <plugin>gz_ros2_control/GazeboSimSystem</plugin>
    </hardware>
    <joint name="left_wheel_joint">
      <command_interface name="velocity">
        <param name="min">-10</param>
        <param name="max">10</param>
      </command_interface>
      <state_interface name="position"/>
      <state_interface name="velocity"/>
    </joint>
    <joint name="right_wheel_joint">
      <command_interface name="velocity">
        <param name="min">-10</param>
        <param name="max">10</param>
      </command_interface>
      <state_interface name="velocity"/>
      <state_interface name="position"/>
    </joint>
  </ros2_control>
  <gazebo>
    <!-- Joint state publisher -->
    <plugin filename="gz_ros2_control-system" name="gz_ros2_control::GazeboSimROS2ControlPlugin">
      <parameters>/home/dave/dev_ws/src/install/my_bot/share/my_bot/config/my_controllers.yaml</parameters>
    </plugin>
  </gazebo>
  <joint name="camera_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="chassis"/>
    <child link="camera_link"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.305 0 0.08"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="camera_link">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.010 0.03 0.03"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="red"/>
    </visual>
  </link>
  <joint name="camera_optical_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="camera_link"/>
    <child link="camera_link_optical"/>
    <origin rpy="-1.5707963267948966 0 -1.5707963267948966" xyz="0 0 0"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="camera_link_optical"/>
  <gazebo reference="camera_link">
    <material>Gazebo/Red</material>
    <sensor name="camera" type="depth">
      <pose> 0 0 0 0 0 0 </pose>
      <visualize>true</visualize>
      <update_rate>10</update_rate>
      <camera>
        <horizontal_fov>1.089</horizontal_fov>
        <image>
          <format>B8G8R8</format>
          <width>640</width>
          <height>480</height>
        </image>
        <clip>
          <near>0.05</near>
          <far>8.0</far>
        </clip>
      </camera>
      <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so" name="camera_controller">
        <frame_name>camera_link_optical</frame_name>
        <min_depth>0.1</min_depth>
        <max_depth>100.0</max_depth>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>
</robot>


However, when I run this file with the command:
ros2 launch my_bot launch_sim_gz.launch.py
Ign Gazebo loads up and displays my robot. However, I see this error first in the output:
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [GUI] [Msg] Using server control service [/server_control]
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [GUI] [Dbg] [Application.cc:569] Applying config
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [GUI] [Msg] Loading plugin [ignition-rendering-ogre2]
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [GUI] [Dbg] [MinimalScene.cc:602] Create scene [scene]
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [GUI] [Msg] Loading plugin [ignition-rendering-ogre2]
[ruby $(which ign) gazebo-1] [Err] [SystemLoader.cc:94] Failed to load system plugin [gz_ros2_control-system] : couldn't find shared library.

... 

[ros2-4] Could not contact service /controller_manager/load_controller
[ERROR] [ros2-4]: process has died [pid 37271, exit code 1, cmd 'ros2 control load_controller --set-state active joint_state_broadcaster'].
[INFO] [ros2-5]: process started with pid [37403]
[ros2-5] Could not contact service /controller_manager/load_controller
[ERROR] [ros2-5]: process has died [pid 37403, exit code 1, cmd 'ros2 control load_controller --set-state active diff_drive_base_controller'].

I have nothing set as $GZ_VERSION - Unsure if that is necessary?
Appreciate the help!

Be aware that there was a name change from ign_ros2_control to gz_ros2_control starting from iron.
Which branch have you built from gz_ros2_control repo? If you have humble version of ros2_control, you also need humble branch of gz_ros2_control. As a consequence, the plugin is called ign_ros2_control. Have a look at the corresponding demos.

Thanks for the comment Christoph. I followed the instructions from the https://github.com/ros-controls/gz_ros2_control/tree/master then clicking Humble | Documentation. Now I realize that flipped me over to ros2_control, not gz_ros2_control.  Still it seems that should have installed from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_ci/master/ros_controls.humble.repos. I will consider going to Jazzy & Harmonic...

the repos file you've linked shows the matching branches for a source build (which is humble for gz_ros2_control)
the humble version of control.ros.org also hosts the gz_ros2_control docs (Simulator Integrations -> Gazebo)
